# A game consists of drawing two cards from a deck of $52$

Tags: probability, statistics

A game consists of drawing two cards from a deck of $52$. Assuming that
all pairs of cards are equally possible, calculate the probability of extracting at least one ace.

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Whenever I see a probability type question ask for the chance of "at least one", the first thing I think of that it's $1$ minus the probability of none. I first learned this with determining the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where it can make a big difference in the complexity of the calculations. Although it doesn't make much difference with just two cards, you may still find it a bit easier to determine the probability of neither card being an ace than there being at least one ace.

Answer (score 1):

What is the chance the first card is not an ace?  Given that it is not, what is the chance the second card is not an ace?  What is the chance neither card is an ace?

Comment: I upvoted, but you may want to add that the only possibilities are no aces in two cards or at least one ace among the two cards.